# Lists and loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have to be able to calculate the revenu per month depending on the number of goats sold per month knowing that every month I sell 20% of the goats I had initially in January. When I try to calculate it through my price_list I can only get 400$ and not the 300$ for the corresponding months.

The variable d is there to know whether or not the month starts with a vowel. If it does d= "d'" and if not d="de".

I have been going at it for a week and can't seem to find a solution for neither of my two problems.

Help would be really appreciated !!!

```
goats=int(input("Enter the number of goats at the beginning of january :"))
    
    year= ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"]
    vowels = "aeiouy"
    price_list = [400,400,400,400,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400]
    d=""
        
    if goats >0:
        for month in range(len(year)):
            goats_left = int(goats*0.8)
            goats_sold = goats - goats_left
            goats = goats_left
            print("At the of the month of {0} {1}  , we will have {2} goats left, monthly revenu: {3} $".format(d,year[month],goats,price_list[i]))
    else:
        print("The number entered is not valid {0}.format(goats))
        goats=int(input("Enter the number of goats at the beginning of january :"))
    
    
    
    
    print("\n")
    print("ANNUAL REVENUE ........................................................ :".format())
    print(goats_sold_list)
```

Comment: You have typos and undefined variables in your code. `goats_sold_list` is not defined. `print("The number entered is not valid {0}.format(goats))` has a missing `"`. `i` in `price_list[i]` is not defined. For what do you use `vowels`? You never set `d`.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to use enumerate as a more pythonic way to iterate over your list and get it's index. I also don't understand your use of `d` anywhere so perhaps clarify how you intended it to be used.

Finally, l don't see `i` or `goats_sold_list` declared anywhere.

This should be a starting point for improvement:

```
goats = int(input("Enter the number of goats at the beginning of january :"))
    
year = ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"]
vowels = "aeiou"
price_list = [400,400,400,400,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400]
d=""
goats_sold_list = []
    
if goats >0:
    for index, month in enumerate(year):
        #int() always rounds down, i.e 0.8 goes to 0
        goats_left = int(goats*0.8)
        goats_sold = goats - goats_left
        goats = goats_left

        goats_sold_list.append(goats_sold)
        print("At the of the month of {0} {1}  , we will have {2} goats left, monthly revenu: {3} $".format(d,month,goats,price_list[index]))
else:
    print("The number entered is not valid {0}.format(goats)")
    goats=int(input("Enter the number of goats at the beginning of january :"))

print("\n")
print("ANNUAL REVENUE ........................................................ :".format())
print(goats_sold_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a definition for `[i]` in `price_list[i]`, barring some outside definition, I think that should be `price_list[month]`.

I don't see `d` being set at any point, you might need to have some line of code setting `d` to some value based on the first letter of the month.